# Batch downloading time series of TIFF images using multi-polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have a working code to download a time series of (monthly) Landsat water surface rasters for a reference region of interest [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b0af141266693954837fe6da61ba8af). Copy-pasting the relevant lines below:

```
var selectCol = JRC_annual.filterDate("1984-1-1", "2019-1-1") 
                   .filterBounds(geometry)
                   .map(function(img){
                     return img.clip(geometry);
                   })
                   .select("waterClass");
var region = geometry.toGeoJSONString();    
var newImg = selectCol.toBands();
print(newImg.getDownloadURL({scale: 30, region: region, name:"Alaska_Annual_1984-2019"}));
```

I have been thinking of ways to scale this to multiple regions with a multi-polygon shapefile, without overloading Earth Engine.

Ideally, the output should be a CSV file with a list of download links with the structure (https://earthengine.googleapis.com/$ID) that can be downloaded with WGET, where ID is a unique identifier of the polygons (grids, for example, that contain not more than 10000 pixels each) in the multi-polygon shapefile.

Alternatively, is there a way to download the whole region (say the size of a continent), even if I have to do it one large image at a time, that exceeds the pixel limits of the getDownload function (i.e. "Pixel grid dimensions [...] must be less than or equal to 10000")?

Is it reasonable to expect GEE to do this without overloading it?

Comment: Does this help?  https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26

Comment: Thanks much, Noel! This looks like what I need (also, perfect that it's with Python, my preferred way to do anything). I also got the link to FTP from JRC (in the meantime), but I definitely want to try and do this with GEE. Timely that your Medium post was made a few weeks ago! If you want to submit it as an answer for a bounty, GEE, thanks!